# Where to put appending of required data (to be passed on API) globally?

Tags: android, rx-java2, clean-architecture

**Clean Architecture Question**

I have many form `activities` that has 1 common data that must be appended during submission, my question is, where will the logic must be placed?

Domain or Presentation Layer?

> For Presentation:

I'll create a `BaseFormActivity` that has a method of inserting the needed data on a `form` that is child of `BaseForm` which contains the needed data globally.

**BaseForm**: (to be extended by all forms)

```
public class BaseForm {
   private String globalData;
   //getter setters...
}
```

**BaseFormPresenter:**

```
public class BaseFormPresenter extends BaseFormMvpView {
   private final GetGlobalDataInteractor mGetData; //to be injected, this is a use case

   public void getGlobalData() {
      mGetData.execute()
         .subscribe(data -> {
             getMvpView().showGlobalData(data);
          }); //just for the sake of simplicity
   }
}
```

**BaseFormActivity:** (which is extended by all activity that handles form)

```
public abstract class BaseFormActivity implements BaseFormMvpView {
   @Inject
   BaseFormPresenter mPresenter;

   //onCreate(), etc
}
```

**SpecificFormActivity:** (extends BaseFormActivity)

```
public class SpecificFormActivity extends BaseFormActivity {

    private SpecificForm mForm; //extends BaseForm

    //onCreate(), etc

    @Override
    public void showGlobalData(String data) {
       mForm.setGlobalData(data);
    }

    //then ill just call the presenter to get the global data before submitting
}
```

> For Domain:

**SubmitSpecificFormInteractor:** (Sorry for the coding, it is just a representation on what I'm thinking to do)

```
public class SubmitSpecificFormInteractor extends SingleUseCase<Return, Param> {

    //to be injected
    GlobalRepository mGlobalRepository; 
    SpecificFormRepository mFormRepository;

    //some initialization

    public Single<SomeResponse> buildObservable(@NonNull String specificFormData, String anotherSpecificFormData) {
       return mGlobalRepository.getGlobalData()
          .map(globalData -> SpecificFormDto.create(
                specificFormData, anotherSpecificFormData, globalData)) //create the dto then append global data
          .flatMap(specificFormDto -> mFormRepository.submit(specificFormDto)) //then submit data
    }
}
```

I'm thinking of placing it on the **domain layer** (you can see that it is much isolated, but I'll have to do it on all form submissions, which is redundancy), but still I just want to **make my decision solid**. **Refactoring is time consuming**. Hope you understand my point here, specially on my pseudocode-like coding. Feel free to comment if there's something hard to understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Clean Architecture all business rules go to use case interactors. The main goal is to keep the business rules independent from any details - from any framework - that includes android as well.

The Clean Architecture then uses "interface adapters" (in UI part called "controllers" and "presenters") to map between data most convenient for the inner circles and data convenient for the frameworks.

So in ur case u should go for ur second proposal - even if that means that u have to call the interactor from multiple places and have to map some data types. it is worth the benefits (business rules free from details).

For a more detailed discussion about use case interactors, controllers and presenters pls refer to my posts here: https://plainionist.github.io/Implementing-Clean-Architecture-UseCases/
and here https://plainionist.github.io/Implementing-Clean-Architecture-Controller-Presenter/

Comment: Thanks for more clarification :)